# Утечка памяти в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Использую класс `AsyncTask`, в котором используются всего 2 метода `doInBackground` и `onProgressUpdate`. В первом методе запускается цикл(n раз). В нём создается соединение `urlConnection` (используя `StringBuilder` и `BufferedReader`), скачивается `dataJsonObj`, достается из него информация и передается в метод `onProgressUpdate`, в котором эта инфа выводится в UI и цикл начинается заного. На эмуляторе всё хорошо работает, но на реальном устройстве некоторые UI пропускаются или отображаются неправильно. В логгах заметил, что в этих местах выводится следующее:

> D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 3688K/3944K, paused 4ms+0ms, total 7ms

Как я понял, это называется утечка памяти и сборщик мусора приостанавливает все процессы, чтобы отчистить ненужные ресурсы и освободить память, в эти моменты как раз и неправильно отображается скачанная инфа. Как это исправить? И правильно ли я понял причину проблемы?
P.S. Пробовал ненужным переменным присваивать `null`, но это не помогло

**UPDATE** Я понял, что память забивается из-за большого количества `new объектов` в цикле, но теперь появился другой вопрос:
Как вытащить

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))`

из цикла или можно каким-то образом обнулять/отчищать `reader` в конце цикла?**
Полный код цикла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount() ; i++) {
 URL url = new URL(adress);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();
 InputStream inputStream;
inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
**BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));**

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    resultJson = buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: А в дэбаг режиме что видно?

Comment: Утечек памяти у вас нет. Это нормальный процесс работы системы, когда она выводит в лог сообщения о расширении хипа, и предшествуюшем ему вызове GC.

Comment: @metalurgus странно.. в моменты вывода этого сообщения в логи происходит сбой в заполнении UI (пропускается элемент или путаются значения) в методе `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: Это происходит по какой-то другой причине. Возможно проблема в вашем `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: @metalurgus если отключить `onProgressUpdate`, то в логах всё равно выводятся

`D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 13% free 3983K/4572K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 6ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 11% free 4023K/4500K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 6ms`
Мне кажется что-то не так в Background`e..

Comment: А я вам выше написал, что такие логи - это нормально!

Comment: @metalurgus хм, тогда не могу представить в чём может быть проблема..

Comment: @metalurgus я задал более точный вопрос, загляните если сможете